# enumerate the number of perfect matchings in directed complete graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to enumerate All the $1$-factors, or perfect matchings, of the complete directed graph $K_{2n}$. Is there an algorithm or method to enumerate all the perfect matchings?

Comment: no not the same I wanted to find All 1-factors in complete directed graph

Comment: What do you mean by a 1-factor of a directed graph? Is each vertex in a single edge or do you want each vertex to have in-degree 1 and out-degree 1?

Comment: For example if we have K2(1,2) so the possible matchings or 1-factors are :
1-2 and 2-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a vertex $v$ in $\vec{K_{2n}}$. To create a perfect matching, this vertex must be in a single edge. There are $2n-1$ ways to choose a neighbor $w$ for $v$ and $2$ ways to orient this edge. Now if we look at the subgraph on the remaining vertices, we see that we want a 1-factor on a complete directed graph with $2n-2$ vertices. So we can continue this process, fix some vertex $u$ other than $v,w$. We have $2n-3$ ways to choose a neighbor for $u$ and $2$ ways to orient this edge...

Overall, the number of 1-factors is 
$$
(2n-1) * 2 * (2n-3) * 2 * (2n-5) * 2 \cdots 5 * 2 * 3 * 2 * 1 *2 = 2^n * (2n-1)!!.
$$
The double factorial is a common notation for this sort of product. Note that
$$
(2n-1)!! = \frac{(2n)!}{2n*(2n-2) *(2n-4) \cdots 4*2} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}.
$$
So the number of 1-factors of $\vec{K_{2n}}$ is 
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{n!}.
$$

Comment: yes logical answer...thank you